# User does not have permission to comment on this post

Tags: support, comments, android-app

I get the error message

> User does not have permission to comment on this post

when trying to post a comment on Stack Overflow. Why can't I post comments/answers?

Comment: You're on the Android app, right?

Comment: [50 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) points are needed to comment everywhere.

Comment: You can't comment (except on your own questions, or answers to your own questions, but I see on SO you have none) because you have only 1 rep.

Comment: The Android app should arguably make that clearer, though. It seems to be doing nothing to explain what is going on. Feature request added: [Android app / API should be more verbose about why a user can't comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220848)

Comment: Thanks Kate, so how many questions do I have to post before I am allowed to post comments on other peoples posts? Also is it possible to prevent other people from editing my posts? My first post was completely rewritten by someone so it was no longer what I asked

Comment: @LeslieHewitt Take a look at the links; whether or not you're allowed to post a comment isn't about how many questions you post. Also, I see what you're getting at with your other post, but to be fair, had it been left alone, it would have been received really poorly (rants as questions are almost universally frowned upon)

Comment: Questions can always be edited by others; there is no way to prevent that. If you really, really dislike an edit, you can roll it back in the edit history - but as Dennis says, the edit was probably a good idea.