# Android app / API should be more verbose about why a user can't comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

According to [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220846/user-does-not-have-permission-to-comment-on-this-post), users of the Android app with less than 50 rep get this message when trying to post a comment:

> User does not have permission to comment on this post

That's arguably spectacularly unhelpful for a new user.

They should receive the same message as on the web site:

> You must have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: I guess attached to this question: are custom error messages sent back through the API, or is it something like -1 or false? That is, does the Android app have to infer what the actual error message is?

Comment: @ChrisForrence API always sends back *an* error message, it varies whether the app passes it straight through or not.  (Also, sometimes the error message comes from "normal" code, not API checks)

Comment: Ah, ok @KevinMontrose. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We looked into this and it turns out that the mobile devices actually flat out use the same error messages as the website. What was happening in that specific case was that the question they were attempting to comment on was locked or protected or something else, rather than them just not having enough reputation to do it.

Comment: Perhaps *"This post is locked and cannot be commented on."* or *"You cannot comment on this post as it is locked."* is better than *"User does not have permission to comment on this post."*